# Is fscrypt encryption FIPS compliant?

Tags: filesystems, encryption

I am considering to use https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/filesystems/fscrypt.html to encrypt directory files and just wondered if the encryption with fscrypt is complaint with FIPS. If so, would it be possible to get the CMVP numbers? If not, is there any plan to get the certification?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the response from the maintainer:

> No, there is no plan to certify fscrypt (kernel part or userspace part) as a FIPS cryptographic module.